# HTTP POST: how to ensure it is called only from a previous page?

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, http-post

This is probably quite a simple, newbie question for seasoned Web developers, which I am not, and googling around does not help.

I have a very simple webapp hosted on Heroku, the code of which is [here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator-demo). It has two JSP pages, one index, one with the validation results, nothing fancy. The two JSP pages are [here (index.jsp)](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator-demo/blob/783c492a6a66c48ffb53ef435c1fc32842180188/src/main/webapp/index.jsp) and [here (results.jsp)](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator-demo/blob/783c492a6a66c48ffb53ef435c1fc32842180188/src/main/webapp/results.jsp).

The problem is with the [validation servlet](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator-demo/blob/4634a3507a513d96a97e1209b050fee8a2da7756/src/main/java/org/eel/kitchen/jsonschema/FormValidation.java): it is a POST, and is triggered, when using the app itself, via an input button in `index.jsp`. But I have tested that it will also work if I call the servlet directly... And I don't want that.

Is there a way to reliably ensure that this servlet may only be called when coming from the index page (and send a 403 otherwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I've used is to have the input form on index.jsp include a hidden field which contains an md5 hash which the results.jsp can also calculate. I use the md5 hash of the client machine's IP address concatenated with a shared secret phrase.

I guess for a given client IP address the hash is always going to be the same so you could also salt it with another value (like current time) which is passed in another hidden field for inclusion in the calculation by results.jsp.

Comment: That looks like a good one. With the drawback that, of course, the code is public so I don't see how I'd have a "secret phrase" ;) I'll dig a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a fingerprint (for example UUID.randomUUID()) when the first page is loaded and save the value in the current session.

When you post the result to the validation servlet you include that fingerprint as a hidden field and check that the fingerprint exists on the session.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can be 100% sure of that. Eventualy you can check the referer but it's possible to forge it. You can also set a cookie when loading the index.jsp and check the value in the servlet. But it's also possible for someone to load index.jsp to retrive the cookie and then use it to post on the validation servlet. Same think with an input hidden with a hash.